# Why is the code not working and giving me the error "CS0103 Add,Subtract etc doesn't exist in current context"

Tags: c#

I was trying to create a simple calculator program in C# and I wanted to make the user input something and it will do that so if the user inputs "add" the calculator would add numbers but when I try to do that it says that add subtract etc dont exist in current context which is very confusing. Heres the code:

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
class I
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Calculator! What do you want to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("a) Add          b) Subtract         c)Multiply         d)Divide");
        string thing = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (thing)
        {
            case thing == Add:
                Console.WriteLine("Add");
                break;
            case thing == Subtract:
                Console.WriteLine("sample");
                break;
            case thing == Multiply:
                Console.WriteLine("Test");
                break;
            case thing == Divide:
                Console.WriteLine("no.");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("these arent important");
                break;
        }
    }   
        

}
```

(dont worry about missing {} I correctly placed them but they made a bit of fuss when copy pasting) In this code I declared a string "thing" as Console.ReadLine; and then I created a switch statement where it will add if you enter add etc. (current responses are just filler)
Now the problem is as I said the code gives Error CS0103 and refuses to work but this is just the same thing as someone's supposedly working code but with the names, responses and cases edited but it doesn't work now? If I make the variable something like "test" instead of Console.ReadLine; It still wouldn't work so what is the problem here? I am completely new so I may be missing something if so please explain. Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to surround those case values with double quotes? Also you don't need the first part of the case e.g. `case "Add":`

Comment: because if you want to compare to a string you have to add quotes. Furthermore the cases in your `switch` are invalid ... If you are switching on `thing` the cases can't evaluate to boolean

Comment: instead of `case thing == Add:`, you have to use `case "Add":`. VTC because this counts as typo... welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). see also [The Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement)

Comment: I tried doing that and yup it it did work thanks for clarifying i think the orignal code i tried was from an old version of c# or it was just wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you don't have double quotes (Add, Subtract) so compiler treats these as variables (you got error), not values.

You should check `string` values and no need to use `==` in `case` statements - `switch(thing)` means you check `thing` variable (its' value) with values in `case` statements:

```
switch (thing)
{
    case "Add":
        Console.WriteLine("Add");
        break;
    case "Subtract":
        Console.WriteLine("sample");
        break;
    case "Multiply":
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        break;
    case "Divide":
        Console.WriteLine("no.");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("these arent important");
        break;
}
```